# Text overlapping slide -unresponsive

Tags: responsive-design

I am using wordpress responsive theme ,but one slide isnt responsive ,Text is overlapping the slide.I Tried this code
`.wpi_slide_image {
        width: 100%
      max-width: 675px;`
But its not working
 [my Website](http://cardmart.tk)

Slide is on the home page 
Here is the screenshot of slide -http://postimg.org/image/p7oafp57d/ 
Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the following css

```
.wpi_slide .wpi_slide_image {
  background-position:50% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

set the width to `49%!important;` and the height to `auto!important;`

remember to put in the !important after the attributes. Its important - lol.

also override this

```
 .wpi_slide_607 .wpi_slide_image { 
   -webkit-filter:blur(0px); 
    background-image:url(cardmart.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/…);
    left:0; 
    opacity:1; 
    top:0; }
```

add in `z-index:1!important;`

also in .wpi_slide_607 and 608 you have to set the width to 49% and height to  auto. do this last. step by step.

Comment: don't adjust the path of the background image!

Comment: `.wpi_slide .wpi_slide_image{ height: auto!important; width: 49%!important; }
.wpi_slide_607 .wpi_slide_image { 
   -webkit-filter:blur(0px); 
    background-image:url(cardmart.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/…);
    left:0; 
    opacity:1; 
    top:0;
  z-index:1!important;
}`
added this in custom css

Comment: Rachel and @wordpressuser, I hope that this is enough of a warning: targeting your upvotes on a user is not acceptable on Stack Overflow. The voting has been undone. **Do not** do this again.